# Import inside protobuf from external module in Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, protocol-buffers

I have an application that works with BLE and uses .proto files and want to make external module. All proto files import the one .proto file that I want to move to this external module, but how can I import this .proto in external libarary from my application module?